# My array doesn't return the same values if i select a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Why does the result from these are not equal while they're the same exact array.

The array is passed down a component and is a react state.

```
const [vars, setVars] = useState([]);
<Message index={vars.findIndex((entry) => entry.NAME === "message")} vars={vars}/>;
```

I print my array using this within the Message component.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(vars[index], vars[index].CONTENT);
}, [index, vars]);
```

The value is OKAY in the `vars[index]` part, but if I do `vars[index].CONTENT` the content ain't right. What's the meaning of this, am I doing something wrong? If you need any other information, feel free to ask me.

*EDIT: Here's the result I got from the console.log*
[image]

Comment: Can you add the result of `console.log(vars[index], vars[index].CONTENT);`, like what does that print to console right now?

Comment: @arfi720 I just added it!

Answer (score 0):

So, the following code works for me.
I initialize vars with some made up state similar to what is being printed out.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Message = ({vars, index}) => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(vars[index], vars[index].CONTENT);
     }, [index, vars]);

    return(
        <div>{vars[index].CONTENT.text}</div>
    )
}

export const App = () => {
    const [vars, setVars] = useState([
        {
            NAME: 'error',
            CONTENT: {
                text: "error text",
                variant: "danger"
            }
        },
        {
            NAME: 'message',
            CONTENT: {
                text: "message text",
                variant: "info"
            }
        },
    ]);

    return(
        <Message index={vars.findIndex((entry) => entry.NAME === "message")} vars={vars}/>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Maybe this isn't the answer to your question but if you are still having an issue, maybe you could post the code where you are calling `setVars`, that is probably where the issue originates.
[image]